# git-svn display svn repository url

Tags: svn, git

My project is setting up using git and upload to svn. However, i forgot what is the svn repository url that is configured with my project. Is there a command line to show that information?

Thanks,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
git svn info
```

That should do the trick